# How to merge css and js files. or how to to call phtml file in magento 2 with css and js files?

Tags: magento2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Frequently asked questions</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="page-header">
    <h1>FAQ<small> Questions and answers</small></h1>
</div>

<!-- Bootstrap FAQ - START -->
<div class="container">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        This section contains a wealth of information, related to <strong>Mysavdo.uz</strong> and its store. If you cannot find an answer to your question, make sure to contact us. 
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="faqHeader">General questions</div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">What is your work schedule?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body" align="justify">
                    <strong>We are working on the following schedule:</strong>
        <br>Call-center:
        <br>- Monday - Friday: from 8-00 to 18-00;
        <br>- Saturday: from 9-00 to 18-00; 
        <br>- Sunday: from 10-00 to 18-00.
        <br>Address Tashkent, st. Dombrabad-17.

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTen">The site indicates that the product is out of stock, can I order it?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTen" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body" align="justify">
                    You can leave your e-mail address and we will send you a notification as soon as the goods appear in stock. 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseEleven">What are the advantages of registration?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseEleven" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body" align="justify">
                    <strong>Registration throw the following possibilities you to:</strong><br>
        - view the history of your orders;<br>
        - receive an e-mail newsletter about new products and promotions  Mysavdo.<br>
        The login for the input (i.e., the field by which the system will be able to recognize you) is the e-mail address.<br>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwelve">How to cancel the order?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwelve" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body" align="justify">
        You can cancel the order by phone (71) 207 31 31.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThirteen">What if the prepaid goods(product) are not delivered?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThirteen" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body" align="justify">
        We insure all the goods that are sent to other cities. In the absence (for any reason) of your goods in the office of the carrier, we will send you a new product within <strong>2 to 3 days.</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFourteen">What is the guarantee that I will receive it after prepayment of the order?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseFourteen" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body" align="justify">
        You have two documents that confirm our cooperation with you: the invoice we issued and the payment document that the bank provides. When transferring money we have a debt obligation to you.  It is repaid only after the signing of the invoice, which will bring the courier for you. Thus, you have all the levers of influence on us: the court, the society for protecting the rights of consumers and others. Also, your interests are protected by the law <strong>"On Protection of Consumer Rights".</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFifteen">What is the guarantee that the goods sent will not be substituted during for in transit?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseFifteen" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body" align="justify">
        Any product is accompanied by a completed warranty card, which indicates its serial number. Thus, any substitution is excluded.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSixteen">Can the cost of the order change while it is being executed?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseSixteen" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body" align="justify">
        The cost of the order is agreed upon at the time of its registration with our manager and remains unchanged until delivery and payment. Also, those promotional offers that were valid at the time of placing the order will be valid.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><br><br>
        <p align="justify"><strong>Warranty obligations do not cover the following faults:</strong><br>
        - natural wear or exhaustion of the resource;<br> 
        - accidental damage caused by the customer or damage resulting from negligence or use (exposure to liquids, dust, ingress of foreign objects, etc.); <br> 
        - damage as a result of natural disasters (natural phenomena); <br> 
        - damage caused by emergency increase or decrease in voltage in the mains or incorrect connection to the mains; <br> 
        - damage caused by defects in the system in which the product was used, or resulting from the connection and connection of the product to other products; <br> 
        - damage caused by the use of the goods for other purposes or in violation of the rules of operation.</p><br>
                 <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSeventeen">Where to go for warranty service?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseSeventeen" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body" align="justify">
        Warranty service is handle by service centers authorized by the manufacturers.<br>

        The right to free warranty service gives a warranty card, which states:<br>
        <strong>•   model;<br>
        •   serial number;<br>
        •   guarantee period;<br>
        •   the date the product was sold.</strong><br>
        Please keep it for the entire lifetime.<br>
        The repair time is determined by an authorized SC, in case of problems with the service partner, you can contact the point of sale.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                 <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseEightteen">What products are warranted?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseEightteen" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body" align="justify">
        The goods in our megamarket are provided with a guarantee that confirms the obligation for the absence of factory defects in the product. The warranty is provided for a period of 2 weeks to 36 months, depending on the manufacturer's service policy. The warranty period is specified in the description of each product on our website. Confirmation of the warranty is the manufacturer's warranty card.
Please check the completeness and the absence of defects in the product upon receipt (the completeness is determined by the product description or the manual for its operation).
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                 <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseNineteen">What is the cost of targeted delivery in Tashkent?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseNineteen" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body" align="justify">
        Delivery within Tashkent is free when ordering cost starts from 200 000 sum. The cost of delivery of orders up to 200 000 sum is 15 000 sum.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                 <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwenty">What do you need to receive goods paid by wire transfer?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwenty" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body" align="justify">
        <strong>For individuals:</strong><br>
        - passport.<br>
        For legal entities<br>
        - power of attorney issued to the bearer<br>
        - a copy of the certificate of the VAT payer (if any).<br>
        Without a power of attorney, the director of the enterprise can receive the goods personally, with the confirmation of the invoices with the round seal of the enterprise.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwentyOne">How can I pay for my order?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwentyOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body" align="justify">
        Currently available methods of payment:<br>
        - cash payment;<br>
        - cashless payment;<br>
        - Through payment systems <strong>Payme, Woywo</strong><br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                 <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwentyTwo">Where and on what terms is the carried delivery out?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwentyTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body" align="justify">
        Terms of delivery vary by region. We deliver goods throughout the city of Tashkent.
Terms of delivery of household appliances and goods from other sellers are slightly different from other products.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                 <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwentyThree">What should I do if the product was damage during transportation?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwentyThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body" align="justify">
        In case of damage to the goods, or incomplete ordering - it is necessary to refuse to receive the goods and pay for it, and also to draw up an act (claim). In case this situation occurs - please inform us about the incident by phone: <strong>(71) 207 31 31, (97) 706 05 85.</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .faqHeader {
        font-size: 27px;
        margin: 20px;
    }

    .panel-heading [data-toggle="collapse"]:after {
        font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
        content: "\e072"; /* "play" icon */
        float: right;
        color: #F58723;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 22px;
        /* rotate "play" icon from > (right arrow) to down arrow */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }

    .panel-heading [data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed:after {
        /* rotate "play" icon from > (right arrow) to ^ (up arrow) */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        color: #454444;
    }
</style>

<!-- Bootstrap FAQ - END -->

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your css style and custom js to your child theme and in admin panel make:

**To merge CSS files:**

Admin panel >> Stores >> Settings >> Configuration >> Developer >> CSS Setting - set Merge Css File Yes

**To merge Js files:**

Admin panel >> Stores >> Settings >> Configuration >> Developer >> JavaScript Setting - set Merge JavaScript Files Yes